# Custom table inside Wordpress article

Tags: wordpress, tabs, tabular

I need a way to create a kind of custom table in each Wordpress article. The table has some regular data/text (that remains the same) and some input data/text (that needs to be changed for each post). Under this it needs to have 2/3 tabs that can contain some pictures.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Is there a plugin or something I can use to create such a table?

Here is how the table looks like.

[image: table design]

Comment: I guess easiest way would be to create a custom shortcode for same.

Comment: I've tried Shortcoder and it works well, but I'm have problems adding the pictures inside the tabs.

Comment: What problem are you facing in adding the pictures? Can explain what you have tried?